# Different execution plan for a different parameter value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query 1 runs fast and uses Parallel execution plan

```
SELECT c.[Date]
FROM Table1 c
left join Table2 bec on bec.Col1ID = c.Col1ID and bec.Active = 1
WHERE c.Active = 1
AND (c.Col2ID not in (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) or c.Col2ID is null) 
and (c.[Date] >= '06/12/2014 02:30:00.000 PM')
```

Query 2 takes longer and uses Normal(Serial) execution plan

```
SELECT c.[Date]
FROM Table1 c
left join Table2 bec on bec.Col1ID = c.Col1ID and bec.Active = 1
WHERE c.Active = 1
AND (c.Col2ID not in (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) or c.Col2ID is null) 
and (c.[Date] >= '06/15/2014 02:30:00.000 PM')
```

Question:

1. Query2 is trying to get a subset data of Query1, so Query2 should be faster.
2. Both the Queries differ only by the parameter value, so why completely different execution plans.

Info about the Server: This is running in SQL Server 2008

Table Structure is as follows:

```
TABLE Table1(
       Col1Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       Col2Id [int] NULL,
       Col3 [int] NOT NULL,
       Col4 [int] NULL,
       Active [bit] NOT NULL
       [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

Index on Table1
Non Clustered on (Active, Date)

```
TABLE Table2(
       [Col] [int] NOT NULL,
       Col1ID [int] NOT NULL,
       [Col2] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Col3] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [Col4] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Col5] [datetime] NULL,
       [Col6] [int] NULL,
       [Active] [bit] NULL)
```

Index on Table2
Non Clustered on [Active] Included (Col, Col1Id)
Clustered on (Col, Col1ID)

Any help on this is welcome.

Comment: Your table structures would be helpful. Also your indexes.

Comment: I just updated the question, Query1 runs in Parallel and Query2 in Serial. Please let me know if still table structures are required.

Comment: Yes. In this way we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Sure Patrick, ill update the question in few minutes. I cant do it immediately because i can not reveal the exact table and column NAMES. Company Policy :(.

Comment: Sorry for the messed up column names

Comment: [This is a common issue with ascending dates](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding included columns to the Table1 index and create a new index on Table2.  Also, make sure statistics are up-to-date.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Table1_Active_Date ON dbo.Table1 (Active, Date) INCLUDE (Col1Id, Col2Id);
CREATE INDEX idx_Table2_Col1ID_Active ON dbo.Table2 (Col1ID, Active);
```